# ms access all the data in my table does not show up in my form

Tags: forms, database-design, ms-access-2007

I hope my question makes sense, I'll try to give as much info as possible.I should probably start off by saying this is the first access database (any database) I have ever done and my knowledge comes from trial and error as well as youtube and the occasional google search...NOOB

So I'm attempting to build a database using microsoft access (2007) for the first time (Student Records in my department). I have pulled in all the data I had available (names, major, graduate, advisor etc.) and made several appended tables for additional data using an append query (usually just pulling over name and ID# and major, and then adding the information that is related to the particular table).

Now I am going through the paper files (which we would like to get rid of) to update any missing data or add new students that we didn't have stored anywhere electronically.

I have created a form in which I can add new records or edit/add already available data that I need.

The problem that I have is that it pretty much pulls up everything I need except the occasional record (which I do a search in the search field on the bottom using the ID#) so I figure hey I must not have this student and add it, when I hit save it basically tells me this record can't be added as there already is a conflicted value. And when I check my table sure enough the record is there. In the form query where I check what tables the field's information is pulled from I have no criteria in there to filter any information out, the relationships overall are just based on the ID# (which is my primary key in all tables). When I check the data everything seems to be correct (not a wrong major, etc.) so I can't quite figure out why some records are not being pulled up.

My question is why and what can I do to fix it...

I hope my explanation is not to confusing. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Please read [ask] and all topics under "Asking" on [help]. Your question has too much text and too little information about the actual problem.

Comment: Forget about the form for the moment.  Take its Record Source query, and open that in the Access query designer.  Does the phantom record exist in the query's result set?  (If it doesn't exist there, it won't appear on a form based on that query.)

Comment: @HansUpOk I have run the query and they don't show up but what I can't seem to figure out is why this is the case.

Comment: @Andre I apologize if my question is to long I was trying to give the most detailed background in hopes it would help solve the problem which is that my form does not pull up all the data that is available in the tables that I am wanting to pull the data from. As per HansUps suggestion I ran the Record Source query and the records do not show up in there however I am not sure why and what I can do to make these records available

Comment: @Loz My guess is your query joins 2 or more tables, and the phantom record is excluded as a consequence of those joins.  But really our best chance at solving this is for you to show us the query SQL and brief samples from its source tables --- a few rows which do appear in the query result set, plus the phantom row, and tell us which sample row is the phantom row.

Comment: @HansUp so I really really appreciate all of your help but because of your wish to see screen shots it made me go through my append queries and what criterias I had. In the end I found one of my tables used in the form had a criteria that excluded the majority of my records. I took the criteria out and now it works like a charm....thank you again for your help as it pushed me in the right direction